# Getting "undefined" in browser when trying to bring text into html template via JS and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference, undefined

I'm working with a separate js document titled "store.js" to keep a variety of content available to insert into an html template defined in index.js. I've created a variety of strings but they aren't being displayed.

I've repaired all the issues in the DOM, so the Start button on the first screen takes me to the next screen without issue.

index.js

```
function renderQuestion() {
    let question = STORE.question;
    const questionTemplate = $( `
    <div class="container">
          <p>${question.questionText}<br></p>
          <form>
              <input type="radio">${question.responses}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.questionOne}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.question}
            </form>
          <button>Submit</button>
      </div>`);
      $("main").html(questionTemplate);
}
```

store.js

```
const STORE = {
    question: [
        {
            questionText: "This is the first question",
            responses: [
                "First response",
                "second response",
                "third response"
            ],
            answer: "first response"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm attempting to show the questionText and responses from Store.js. After pressing start I expect to see the question and the responses underneath.

https://repl.it/@BethanyIleene/Question-App-V3

Comment: You get `undefined` because `STORE.question` is an array, hence you have to specify which element of the array you want to access.

Comment: How do I specify the element? Is my syntax in index.js or store.js wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`STORE.question` is an array, hence you have to specify which element of that array you want to access/render:

```
function renderQuestion() {
    let question = STORE.question[0];
    const questionTemplate = $( `
    <div class="container">
          <p>${question.questionText}<br></p>
          <form>
              <input type="radio">${question.responses}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.questionOne}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.question}
            </form>
          <button>Submit</button>
      </div>`);
      $("main").html(questionTemplate);
}
```

This would always select the first element in the array which doesn't make much sense (imho). Therefor I would change how `renderQuestion` works and introduce a parameter which will be the question that should be rendered:

```
function renderQuestion(question) {
    const questionTemplate = $( `
    <div class="container">
          <p>${question.questionText}<br></p>
          <form>
              <input type="radio">${question.responses}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.questionOne}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.question}
            </form>
          <button>Submit</button>
      </div>`);
      $("main").html(questionTemplate);
}

renderQuestion(STORE.question[0]);
```

With that change you can define which question of the array will be added to the DOM.

I would also change the name of the `question` property from singular to plural so it better reflects the fact that there can/will be more than one question in the array.

store.js

```
const STORE = {
    questions: [
        {
            questionText: "This is the first question",
            responses: [
                "First response",
                "second response",
                "third response"
            ],
            answer: "first response"
        }, {
            questionText: "This is the second question",
            responses: [
                "First response",
                "second response",
                "third response"
            ],
            answer: "second response"
        }
    ]
}
```

index.js

```
function renderQuestion(question) {
    const questionTemplate = $( `
    <div class="container">
          <p>${question.questionText}<br></p>
          <form>
              <input type="radio">${question.responses}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.questionOne}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.question}
            </form>
          <button>Submit</button>
      </div>`);
      $("main").html(questionTemplate);
}
```

With these changes you would be able to, e.g., render one specific question with:

```
renderQuestion(STORE.questions[index]);
```

```js
const STORE = {
    questions: [
        { questionText: "This is the first question", responses: [ "First response", "second response", "third response"], answer: "first response" },
        { questionText: "This is the second question", responses: [ "First response", "second response", "third response"], answer: "second response" }
    ]
}

function renderQuestion(question) {
    const questionTemplate = $( `
    <div class="container">
          <p>${question.questionText}<br></p>
          <form>
              <input type="radio">${question.responses}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.questionOne}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.question}
            </form>
          <button>Submit</button>
      </div>`);
      $("#main").html(questionTemplate);
}

renderQuestion(STORE.questions[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Or (if you replace `.html()` with `.append()`) to print all questions from the store with

```
STORE.questions.forEach(renderQuestion);
```

```js
const STORE = {
    questions: [
        { questionText: "This is the first question", responses: [ "First response", "second response", "third response"], answer: "first response" },
        { questionText: "This is the second question", responses: [ "First response", "second response", "third response"], answer: "second response" }
    ]
}

function renderQuestion(question) {
    const questionTemplate = $( `
    <div class="container">
          <p>${question.questionText}<br></p>
          <form>
              <input type="radio">${question.responses}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.questionOne}<br>
              <input type="radio">${question.question}
            </form>
          <button>Submit</button>
      </div>`);
      $("#main").append(questionTemplate);
}

STORE.questions.forEach(renderQuestion);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: The second and third radio button will still be `undefined` because there are no corresponding properties (`questionOne`, `question`) in the questions.